# Count specific categories which occur in mutiple columns

Tags: r, count

My data looks like this: I want to count how often each category occurs in my dataframe.

Preferred output would be:

Analytics = 6

Ads=2

Identifcation= ..
[..]

```
tracker_category <- data.frame = c("Tracker1", "Tracker2", "Tracker3", "TrackerN"), 
c1 = c("Analytics", "Crash", "Location", "Identification", "Analytics", "Ads"), 
c2 = c("Ads", "Analytics", "Location", "Analytics", "Identification", "Ads"), 
c2 = c("Identification", "Analytics", "Ads", "Ads", "Analytics", "Location"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `table` after you have used `unlist` to count the occurrences.

```
table(unlist(tracker_category))
#unlist(tracker_category) |> table() #Alternative since R 4.1.0
#           Ads      Analytics          Crash Identification       Location 
#             5              6              1              3              3
```

Data:

```
tracker_category <- data.frame(
  c1 = c("Analytics", "Crash", "Location", "Identification", "Analytics", "Ads"), 
  c2 = c("Ads", "Analytics", "Location", "Analytics", "Identification", "Ads"), 
  c2 = c("Identification", "Analytics", "Ads", "Ads", "Analytics", "Location"))
```

Comment: Hi, the data frame was just a example of mine - it inclueds  also other collums with not nessesary information which i do not need. In order to this i can not use the hole dataframe just the three columns I posted. There is now a error :"all arguments must have the same length"

Comment: In case you want only specific columns you can subset them like e.g. for column 1 and 3: `table(unlist(tracker_category[c(1,3)]))`.